# Why xpath query fails for alphanumeric values?

Tags: xml-parsing, xpath-2.0

I have an XML :-

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
     <sample>
       <book year="2005">
          <title>Tower</title>
          <author>Niven</author>
          <author>Pournelle</author>
          <publisher>Pocket</publisher>
          <isbn>0743416910</isbn>
          <price>5.99</price>
       </book>
       <book year="2005ad">
          <title>Burning</title>
          <author>Larry</author>
          <publisher>ABC</publisher>
          <isbn>096543</isbn>
          <price>0.99</price>
        </book>
      </sample>
```

I am using XPath to get all the fields using the year.

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setNamespaceAware(true); 
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = builder.parse("sample.xml");

    XPathFactory xpathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xpath = xpathfactory.newXPath();

    XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//book[@year=2005]/*");


    // xpath.compile("//book[@year=2005ad]/*");
    Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;

    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {

        Element el = (Element) nodes.item(i);
        System.out.println("tag: " + el.getNodeName());

        if (el.getFirstChild().getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE)
            System.out.println("inner value:" + el.getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
    }
```

When I use 
           XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//book[@year=2005]/*");
I get proper output data.

However when i use 
        xpath.compile("//book[@year=**2005ad**]/*");
I dont get any output data.

Whenever any alphanumeric data for "year" is used, I don not get any data.
I am confused why this problem occurs.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround is to do it like this (with quotes):

```
//book[@year="2005ad"]
```